# How to embed a github repo into an HTML website

Tags: html, jquery, git, github, jquery-plugins

I was looking into how to embed a github repo into a website, I don't know what's the best way to do this, So far what I've found is this JQuery, plugin called [Repo.js](https://github.com/darcyclarke/Repo.js) Is this the best approach? If so, how do I use it, I am a beginner in this so I've no clue how to download and use a JQuery plugin and the repo documentation doesn't explain too much.
The just told me to add this code

```
$('body').repo({ user: 'darcyclarke', name: 'Repo.js' })
```

but I added it and nothing happens.
Could you please tell me the most appropiate practice for embedding a github repo into a website step by step?
Than you so much, I am sorry if it's an stupid question but I am a beginner. Sorry.

Comment: Are you getting a JavaScript error? Can you [edit] your question to include the HTML of the page your are embedding the repository on?

Comment: You have to load the plugin (and jQuery) here you can find more details https://hannahdnallen.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/steps-to-installing-a-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to use Repo.js

First add jQuery and the plugin to your website:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" />
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darcyclarke/Repo.js/master/repo.min.js" />
```

then

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('body').repo({ user: 'darcyclarke', name: 'Repo.js' })
    });
</script>
```